# Не работает клавиатура в телеграм-боте на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, telebot

После изменений в коде и последующем откате перестала работать клавиатура в виде кнопок. Просто не появляется после написания команды start. Бот раскинул на heroku. Использовал TelegramBotAPI и Flask. Клава помечена комментарием #keyboard. Код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAEEhRFiX_JWeptNfHPbJw2weqLL1e-75AACDQADwDZPE6T54fTUeI1TJAQ")

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    but1 = types.KeyboardButton("Цитаты для мотивации")
    but2 = types.KeyboardButton("Поддержка")

    markup.add(but1, but2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать!Я бот,который поддержит \`людей.').format(message.from_user, bot.get_me((), parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup))`
```

Comment: Переходит по чужим ссылкам не очень интересно, Правила сайта говорят о помещении здесь минимального рабочего кода, воспроизводящего проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы что-то странное накодили. Вот вам решение

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAEEhRFiX_JWeptNfHPbJw2weqLL1e-75AACDQADwDZPE6T54fTUeI1TJAQ")

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add("Поддержка", "Цитаты для мотивации")

    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        text='Добро пожаловать!Я бот,который поддержит людей.',
        reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Благодарю! Действительно много лишнего накостылял))